# edit a textbox with procedure on Delphi

Tags: delphi, procedure

i'm just trying to make a new procedure so i don't need to rewrite it again.
i'm very sorry cause i'm new in delphi. i just wanna make a simple code on writing dnname.text but i don't wanna write it in every event.

like this

```
   procedure link ;
   var
   dbnam : string;
   form : Tform1;

   begin
   dbnam := 'squire';
   form.dnname.text := dbnam;

   end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    link;
    end;
    procedure Tmain.activate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    link;
    end;

    procedure Tmain.datachange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
    begin
    link;
    end;
```

but i've got error on 0074A43C6 from Form1.

Comment: Is the error an "Access violation at address 0074a43c6"? Please specify the exact error message.

Answer (score 2):

The variable declaration

```
var
  form : TForm1
```

only tells the compiler which **type** (TForm1) the variable has, but not which instance of this form should be used (there could be many forms of type TForm1 instantiated). In Delphi, you have to **always** initialize local variables before you use them.

You have a couple of options:

- Do not use a local variable, but use the global form instance instead (it should be called `Form1` in your case). But in this case your utility function is bound to a specific form instance, which is usually not a good idea.
- Implement your utility function as a method of class `TForm1`. In this case you can reference the form instance implicitly or using `Self`.
- Pass the form instance as a parameter to your utility function.

Answer (score 2):

The default, Delphi generated, code for a new form will look something like this:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  { lots of stuff }
  end
```

This describes what "TForm1" looks like but does not create an "instance" of one.

(think of an "instance" as a UFO: just because you told me what the UFO looked like doesn't mean that there **is** a UFO. You have to actually create one for me to think you're not crazy)

You will also see something like the following in the same file:

```
 var
  Form1: TForm1;
```

This allocates some memroy to store an instanance of TForm1, but, also, does not create one.

In your .dpr file you may see something like this:

```
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

That creates and instance of TForm1 and stores it in the variable Form1.

You can also do a similar thing manually:

```
  Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil)
```

That also creates an instance of TForm1 and stores it in the variable Form1.

Your (slightly simplified) supplied code, looks like this:

```
procedure link;
var
  form1: TForm1:
begin
  form1.dnname.text := 'squire';
end;
```

In the context of procedure "link", "form1" has not been assigned a value, therefore it will contain a random value
(this is not entirely true, but will surfice for now)

You will either need to assign "form1" a (valid) value or ensure that "form1" already references a valid value.

The following may work for you:

```
procedure link;
begin
  form1.dnname.text := 'squire';
end;
```

But please, **please**, take the time to understand what is happening.

There will be a lightbuld moment.

And I can assure you that every single super-high-karma stack overflow poster has had that lightbulb moment for themselfs...

Answer (score 1):

Local variable `form` is not initialized here, so Access Violation occurs.

Would you transform this procedure to TForm method - to freely using form components?

Comment: if transform to Tform method i guess, its the same if i write dnname.text = 'squire'; in Tform1.button1lick

Comment: Show us real code, please. Code "Edit1.text := 'Test'" works for me, of course